# SQL query to search for value1 or value 2 or both and if neither return all

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a query that returns results based on the contents of two different columns.

- if either COLUMN_1 contains value1 OR COLUMN_2 contains value2 --> return the matching results
- if COLUMN_1 contains value1 AND COLUMN_2 contains value --> return matching results
- if neither condition is present --> return all values

---

The first condition can be solved with an OR case.
The second condition by an AND case.
The third returns all since there are no condition.

---

This is the query I wrote but I'm uncertain if it returns the desired results.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE 
COLUMN_1 LIKE 'value1%' AND COLUMN_2 LIKE 'value2%' 
ODER BY sno DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking of something like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE (COLUMN_1 LIKE '$value1%' or $value1 is null) AND
      (COLUMN_2 LIKE '$value2%' or $value2 is null)
ORDER BY sno DESC;
```

In practice, you would use parameters rather than inserting parameter values directly into the string.  So, this is an illustration of the logic.

Comment: Yes in practice I do use parameters rather than values.

Comment: how does $value1 is null work out in the WHERE condition.
Will it be like 
    WHERE true AND COLUMN_2 is LIKE 'value2%; .... 
Trying to understand what will happen when  $value1 is null

Comment: @AbilashAmarasekaran . . . That is exactly how it is evaluated -- assuming the "empty" value is passed in as `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

**TSQL**

```
    IF (select count(*) 
        from table
        where (column_1 like '%value1%' OR column_2 like '%value2%')) > 0)
    BEGIN
        select *
        from table
        where (column_1 like '%value1%' OR column_2 like '%value2%')
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        select *
        from table
    END
```

**MYSQL**

```
   IF (select count(*) 
        from table
        where (column_1 like '%value1%' OR column_2 like '%value2%')) > 0) THEN
     select *
        from table
        where (column_1 like '%value1%' OR column_2 like '%value2%')
   ELSE
        select *
        from table 
   END IF;
```